# Insert csv data on certain range of date in python and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I just want only a certain date to be insert into my table. I have this code.

When I used only this code, all of data in csv inserted

```
for row in readers:
     query4 = """INSERT INTO csv(
                 csv_id, Mchn, EnNO, Mode1,
                 IODMd, Date_Time)
                 VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%r)
                 """

     db.session.execute(query4 % (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[4], row[5], row[6],))
db.session.commit()
```

but I want only a certain date to be insert
so I try this add WHERE on it. Like this

```
for row in readers:
    query4 = """INSERT INTO csv(
                csv_id, Mchn, EnNO, Mode1,
                IODMd, Date_Time)
                VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%r)
                WHERE Date_Time >= (select c_start_date from c_temp c where c.id = :id)
                AND Date_Time <= (select DATE_ADD(c_end_date,interval 1 day) from c_temp c where c.id = :id)"""

     db.session.execute(query4 % (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[4], row[5], row[6],))
db.session.commit()
```

But when I try it, it has an error and stop it. Thank you.

Comment: python is not sql.  So, if your creating insert statements via python, you have to filter the data in python.

Comment: also, `query4` is only executing the last row, and not _each_ row.  I would probably generate the SQL insert statements and put the created strings in a list, then create a single transaction to INSERT.

Comment: Hi monkut, I mean MYSQL I edit the title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the data to insert based on the datetime of the data, you should be evaluating the data *before* you create the INSERT statement.

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime(<value from db>)
db_end_date = datetime.datetime(<value from db>)
end_date = db_end_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

for row in readers:
     csvid, mchn, enno, model, iodmd, dt = row[:7]
     # parse incoming datetime value into a python datetime object
     # not sure what your format is here
     parsed_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%D")
     if start_date <= parsed_date <= end_date:
         query4 = """INSERT INTO csv(
                     csv_id, Mchn, EnNO, Mode1,
                     IODMd, Date_Time)
                     VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%r)
                  """

         db.session.execute(query4 % (csvid, mchn, enno, model, iodmd, dt,))
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Hi I tried it but it gives me a syntax error. Especially when I assign

start_date = select c_start_date from c_temp c where c.id = :id

Comment: yes, you're going to need to figure out how to query the db and get the value.